# Retornar un array de elementos html con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente:

```
elementos = function(param){
       return document.querySelectorAll(param)
}

elementos('.link').onclick=function(){
       //Codigo
}
```

Me notifica error.

Lo que quiero más exactamente hacer es algo parecido al método jquery para seleccionar múltiples selectores: $(".a, #botón")

¿Qué me falta o cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

El método `document.querySelectorAll(param)` retorna una lista de elementos que cumplen con el query, por lo que no se puede usar simplemente `.click` sobre su resultado como en jQuery, se tiene que recorrer cada uno de los elementos y asignarle la función `click` uno por uno, esto lo puedes hacer con `forEach`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".link").forEach(function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
    alert("Hola Mundo");
  }
});
```

```html
<a class="link">Enlace 1</a>
<a class="link">Enlace 2</a>
<a class="link">Enlace 3</a>
<a class="link">Enlace 4</a>
```